# SQL Query to Return SUMS and Count Ordered by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the two following tables:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6MyA.png)
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb7dn.png)

What I want to do is to have a query that returns a SUM of PIT_VALORTOTAL, PIT_VOLUME and a count of PED_IDPESSOA per date. What I have so far is:

```
SELECT SUM(PIT_VALORTOTAL) AS VALORTOTAL, SUM(PIT_VOLUME) AS VOLUME, COUNT(DISTINCT PED_IDPESSOA) AS PESSOA FROM PEDIDOS_ITENS INNER JOIN PEDIDOS ON PIT_IDPEDIDO = PED_ID;
```

And it returns the sums and the count correctly, but I don't have a clue on how to get these seperatly per dates. So what I have is this:

```
VALORTOTAL       | VOLUME             | PESSOA  |
49783.2000000    |       679780.360000|   11    |
```

And what I want is something like:

```
| DATE      | VALORTOTAL    | VOLUME     | PESSOA  |
| 2017-09-03| 1012,00       |       1209 |   12    |
| 2017-09-03| 2012,00       |       1450 |   10    |
| 2017-09-03| 3016,00       |       2500 |   20    | 
| 2017-09-03| 3016,00       |       3200 |   5     |
| 2017-09-03| 2016,00       |       4000 |   9     |
```

Comment: Why are all the dates in your example 2017-09-03?  Since the other 3 fields are aggregates I would expect them to sum together for the same date.  Did you mean for those to be different "dates?"  Gordon is likely correct but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something else we're missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `group by`:

```
SELECT PED_DATA, SUM(PIT_VALORTOTAL) AS VALORTOTAL, SUM(PIT_VOLUME) AS VOLUME,
       COUNT(DISTINCT PED_IDPESSOA) AS PESSOA
FROM PEDIDOS_ITENS pi INNER JOIN
     PEDIDOS p
     ON PIT_IDPEDIDO = PED_ID
GROUP BY PED_DATA
ORDER BY PED_DATA
```

Comment: But I also need to have the PED_DATA returned to me. How can I get it?

Comment: @William I'm missing something: `SELECT PED_DATA,` would reutrn PED_DATA...